# assembly code for Poisoning kernel stack

Tags: security, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

[image]
I want to know how the code in picture achieve poisoning the stack.
Please give an explanation for each code.

Comment: Please, **do not post images of code**. Instead, copy and paste it as text, directly into the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
void* low, *high;
IoGetStackLimits(&low, &high);
memset(low, esp - low, 0xaa);
```

It just fills the stack with value `0xaa`.